# Rails, AJAX: Render new link_to depending on previously clicked link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

so I'm just trying to do something simple but I can't seem to find any sort of solution in my books or easily googling it.

```
<div id="subscribe">
<% if session[:read_random]
    unless is_subscribed?(session[:read_random].last)%>
            <%= link_to 'Subscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :post, remote: :true %>

    <% else %>
        <%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :delete, remote: :true %>

<%  end
   end %>
</div>
```

and my create.js.erb is:

```
if is_subscribed?(session[:read].last)
    $('#subscribe').html("Unsubscribe");
else
    $('#subscribe').html("Subscribe");
end
```

so I know that this code is OBVIOUSLY wrong, just please tell me what I'm doing wrong here, I would like to give the user the option to subscribe if he is not and vice versa if he is subscribed.

Do I need to put link_to inside the html portion of the jQuery statements?  The only issue is, I though I would try this to see if it works, and I'm not even getting any updated text from the ajax call. Server says it has rendered subscriptions/create.js.erb and the database is being updated appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: in views/subscriptions/create.js.erb and destroy.js.erb

```
$('#subscribe').html("<%=j link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :delete, remote: :true %>");
```

alter for destroy and there you have it!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is an issue with the controller. Maybe we could see the controller... If you use Firebug of webkit tools do you recieve any errors?

Your javascript is wrong as it is mixing ruby and javascript:

```
<% if is_subscribed?(session[:read].last) %>
    $('#subscribe').html("Unsubscribe");
<% else %>
    $('#subscribe').html("Subscribe");
<% end %>
```

Your is_subscribed method would be better place within a model and it would be better querying the models attributes rather than using the session. This is just a recommendation however. I presume is_subscribed? is defined in a helper?

Sorry I cant help more at this time